# Intersection of collection of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can not find the flaw in my reasoning: a collection of sets being a set itself, so, as the empty set is a subset of every set, the empty set is an element of the collection. So the intersection of a collection of set is always empty. Can someone help in correcting me? Thx

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What "collection" of sets? Do you mean the power set?

Comment: You seem to have invoked the incorrect implication "if something is a subset of a set, then it is also an element of that set".

Comment: $1$ is an element of $\{1,2,3\}$ but not its subset. $\{1\}$ is a subset of $\{1,2,3\}$ but not its element. $\emptyset=\{\}$ is a subset of the set of sets but we can't say in general that it is an element of the set of sets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set. It doesn't follow from this it is an element of *every* collection of subsets of a set. For instance, it is not an element of $\bigl\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\}\bigr\}$.